# Listbox with 2 asymmetric columns- Windows phone 8.1/Windows 8.1

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I want to create somekind of listbox with 2 asymmetric columns.
It looks like that:
[image: a busy cat]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ItemContainerStyleSelector** or **ItemTemplateSelector** and toggle between two templates/styles with alternating left and right margin (or content alignment, etc.).

Comment: But how I determine which one is the right and which one is the left? How do I set them together in the same row?

Comment: Actually I don't know, but I'd try to start with the following: SelectStyle and SelectTemplate get the list item. As there is no way to determine the current index in the list, i'd add a number to these list items and just check if it's even or odd.

Comment: I know it's a kind of q&d solution. If you have the time, you should go with Marcos Idea and implement an own panel. But that's a really advanced topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a new Layout and used it as Item Container of the List Box as said Kai Brummund

You have an example in:
[http://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomLayoutPanel.html][1]

Your panel is very simple. It's very similar to a Stack panel and should have no problems, but if you need help with this ask us again.

Comment: I took the wrap panel code from silverlight, and I had tried to suit (and port) it to my goal, but it's not perfect (and includes a lot of unused code).

I will glad to see example from scratch, in order to understand better.

Thanks!